# reset() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given in Gii after update Yii version

Tags: yii, gii

After updating Yii to 1.1.20 I get the error 
`reset() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given` when clicking the `diff` option in **Model** generator.

I found the function in https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/gii/components/Pear/Text/Diff/Engine/native.php#L194 and https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/gii/components/Pear/Text/Diff/Engine/native.php#L206

So i cannot find the solution.

[image]

Comment: Please report to https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues mentioning that it is a regression.

Comment: There is already an issue, but yii1 just get php incompatibility and security fixes
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/4226

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around this problem change the framework file (not recommended)

```
framework/gii/components/Pear/Text/Diff/Engine/native.php
```

On line 194 and 206 check if $match is an array and skip the code part which depends on that.

Comment: Thanks, l.196 and l.209 work for me (Yii 1.1.21). Like you said, it is not recommended.